# Does findViewById have any side effects?

Tags: android

I'm looking at some code that has a call to `findViewById` without assigning the result or doing anything with it, and want to make sure that's safe to remove. Is there ever a case where someone might call this without doing anything with the result?

Comment: AFAIK there are no side effects, by the way you can check the sources to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I did, but it looks like it ends up in a polymorphic call to findViewTraversal and didn't want to check every subclass possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

findViewById() has no side-effect, at least in the Views that ship with the Android platform. I cannot guarantee what custom Views do in apps.

Comment: Wow. In 2 short sentences you answered my question and let me know what exceptions can be possible. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of this method isn't stored you can delete it safetly, hasn't got any side-effects.

Regards.